# Is there a command to ignore the following character?

Tags: macros, tex-core

Is there a command that ignores the following character, in the same way that `\^` puts a hat over the following character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if one exists already, but issuing the directive

```
\def\?#1{}
```

will do the trick: `\?abc` gives `bc`, and so on.

**Edit:** Here is a discussion of the question Tim N raised in the comments: getting a `\caption` to drop the final period in a figure number.  It does *not* work, even in the default `article` class, to just let

```
\renewcommand*\thefigure{\arabic{figure}\?}
```

which gives a few errors, the first of which is actually "Argument of `\?` has an extra `}`" and not "Paragraph ended before `\?` was complete" (that's the second).  A little `\tracingmacros`-trawling reveals the following phenomenon: when `\caption` is called, it first increments the `figure` counter, which calls `\refstepcounter` so it can be referenced, which sets up (using `\edef`) the current label `\@currentlabel` for `\ref`, which (finally) must contain the value of `\thefigure`!  And guess what: the extra period does not appear after `\thefigure` in *this* context, so the `\?` gobbles *the closing brace of the `\edef` command*.  Hence the error.

Let's see if we can get what you want.  The caption line is constructed in several stages, which in `article` consist of the following discrete steps:

- Generate the caption "number" (the text "Figure 1.2.", for example);
- Attach it to the caption "text" (the argument of `\caption`) by, for example, inserting a colon and a space between them.

These correspond to the internal macros `\fnum@figure` and `\@makecaption`, which are defined by the document class, and obviously vary; it seems that Tim N's packages are putting extra periods in, but who knows whether it's in the first stage or the second?  Or even in `\thefigure` itself?  Depending on where it happens, you need a different workaround:

- If someone erroneously defined `\thefigure` to contain an extra period, and you know how the rest of the number ought to look, then you can just redefine it.  Since there's no way to gobble the *previous* character, if my solution below doesn't work for you, then you should try this.
- If `\fnum@figure` somehow puts a period after the value of `\thefigure`, then *under some circumstances* you will be able to remove it using `\?`.  For example, if they modified the default `article` definition (see below) then putting `\?` right after `\thefigure` will do the trick.  However, if they produce the period by some clever device, you will have to be equally clever to unravel it.

Here is that definition:

```
% The default def'n doesn't have the period
\def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure.}
```

- Finally, suppose that the period is inserted in `\@makecaption`.  Then you *may* be able to catch it with `\?`, but only if the command that produces the "number" is dropped in as-is and not fully expanded first.  This is the case in the `article` class and, we hope, also in whatever your situation is.

So it appears the goal is to stick `\?` right after `\thefigure` *as it appears in `\fnum@figure` only*.  You want to patch a command, and there are several ways to go about this, but the `etoolbox` package is generally useful so I'll go with it.  See the following minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Cute but not necessary here:
% \def\?#1{}

% BAD:
% \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}\?}

% GOOD:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\fnum@figure{\thefigure}{\thefigure\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Since we are going with `\makeatletter` anyway, I figure the internal `\@gobble` command that Yiannis pointed out is probably the wiser course, though `\?` is nice if you are putting it in ordinary text.

Comment: In the LaTeX kernel you find `\@gobble`.

Comment: @Yiannis: Oops, yes.  Though it does need to be swaddled in `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.

Comment: My goal was an ugly hack, to `\renewcommand` `\thefigure` to end with this, because for some interaction between packages, my figure captions started showing up as "Figure 1.2.:" with an extra period. The period can be made invisible by ending with `\color{white}`, but trying to `\?` it results in: `! Paragraph ended before \? was complete.`

Comment: I should add that ending with `\^` does put a hat over the dot.

Comment: You mention "because for some interaction between packages". There could be other ways around this, for which one would need to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. However, for now, this question is most likely "answered". You could post a follow-up question. See [I've just been told I have to post a follow-up question, why and how?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)

Comment: @Werner: There's most likely a "better" solution. This question isn't about solving my problem, though; it's about getting a command that works like `\^` but removes the following character instead of putting a hat on it. None of these solution do that in all situations, and I see no reason for that to be impossible.

Comment: @TimN: Does my new answer work?  By the way: both of the existing answers *do* remove the following character in all situations; the error you observe is from a subtle issue of expansion.  My `\?` is expandable, so destroys the `\edef` in which it appears; `\^`, however, is not expandable, so the accent command just gets carried along in `\@currentlabel` until it is used.  See what happens when you write `\ref{that figure} some more text`; I'm betting you get a hat over the `s`.

Comment: @Ryan: Thank you very much for the explanation. This does not solve the issue, so I'll live with it and solve it properly for my next report instead.

Comment: @RyanReich wouldn't `\protected\def\?#1{}` work? (or, without eTeX, using `\protect`).

Comment: @Bruno: Hmm, that does seem to be the *entire purpose* of `\protected` :)  That would certainly kill the error though then you have a rogue `\?` waiting to surprise you when you use `\ref`.

Comment: @RyanReich then perhaps `\protected\def\?{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\@currenvir}{figure}=\z@\expandafter\@gobble\fi}`? That would only gobble if you're in the figure environment. Not very robust, though.

Comment: As a general observation I don't think the discussion about Tim's problem should be in this thread because nobody will be able to find it.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: When there's another thread for it to be in, I'll move it there.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following:

```
\newcommand*\swallow[1]{}
```

It simply consumes its argument but doesn't use it.

Comment: My goal was an ugly hack, to `\renewcommand` `\thefigure` to end with this, because for some interaction between packages, my figure captions started showing up as "Figure 1.2.:" with an extra period. The period can be made invisible by ending with `\color{white}`, but trying to `\swallow` it results in: `! Argument of \swallow has an extra }.`

Comment: @TimN: Then the dot is added outside of the current brace group. You might want to use the `caption` package instead to change the caption format.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I see. Still, `\^` does what it does, so I suppose it's not impossible to solve?

Comment: I have a dirty mind.