# ToC style of glossary: dots between cross-refs and page ref

Tags: glossaries, xindy

I use the glossaries package for acronyms and a notation list. I'd like a ToC style for my glossaries, meaning with trailing dots up to the left side of the page and the reference of the first use page there.

I use Xindy, and I use cross-references with the `see` key in the notation glossary. I'd like to keep an altlist-like style, something like:

[image: Glossary <br/> A list of terms I find deemed to be defined. blabla expanding over two lines blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla. See Notations......................................40]
(this is an image edit of current situation)

I had a look at the glossaries manual, in particular:

- [the documentation of the see key](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#dx1-27105), which specify that "the cross-referencing information [...] forms part of the number list";
- [the (general) number list section](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:numberlists) which gives tools for option 1 (using TeX for indexing) to do what I'd like, but not for makeindex nor xindy options;
- [the Xindy-dedicated number list section](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:xindyloc), particularly the [`GlsSetXdyLocationClassOrder`](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#dx1-53051) command, allowing to change the order of the categories of references (see below);
- [the custom cross-references section](http://ftp.oleane.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:customxr), for the `\glsseeformat` allowing to redefine the format of the reference.

So, I began investigating the style. I looked at the source of the list styles and found out that what I want to change (references, cross-references, and what comes after: those 3 are actually one big something that is given as a 2nd argument to`glossentry`) is not in the style definition. Hence, I simply use the style I want: `\setglossarystyle{altlist}`.

From the see key documentation, I understood I needed to investigate the number lists. In the xindy-dedicated part of the package documentation, I got the idea of inverting the cross-refs with the "normal" refs, using:

```
\GlsSetXdyLocationClassOrder{%
  "see"
  "arabic-page-numbers"
  "arabic-section-numbers"
  "roman-page-numbers"
  "Roman-page-numbers"
  "alpha-page-numbers"
  "Alpha-page-numbers"
  "Appendix-page-numbers"
}
```

(In the default definition, everything is identical except that the "see" field is placed last.)

Then I needed to add dots between cross-references (XRefs) and normal references. I did not find a command to modify the format of the (actual) references list (normal references only thus), so instead of adding dots *before* the reference, I added them after the XRefs (which leads to the first problem) using:
`\renewcommand*{\glsseeformat}[3][\seename]{\emph{#1} \glsseelist{#2}\dotfill}`

**First problem:**
I have my dots, but only for entry *with* cross-references.
**EDIT**: solved. I looked at the generated files and noticed the page numbers were printed by the \glsXpageXglsnumberformat command; command that is defined at the beginning of those files. So I used `\glossarypreamble` (instead of `\glossaryheader` to not interfere with styles) as an entry point. A few points about the solution found:

- Reading @nicola-talbot's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110680), I use the `\leaders` command instead of `\dotfill`;
- To stop the dots on "one column" like in the ToC, I place the page number in a box of fixed width;
- However, the description wraps above the number instead of wrapping where the dots stop as in the ToC. I haven't figured that out yet.

So here is the current code:

```
\renewcommand*\glossarypreamble{
    \renewcommand*\glsXpageXglsnumberformat[2]{%
        \unskip\xleaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill%
        \makebox[\widthof{0000}][r]{%
            \setentrycounter[##1]{page}\glsnumberformat{##2}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

**Second problem:**
After the dots, Xindy style adds a comma as a delimiter between the different reference types used.

These two problems are shown on the second attached figure:
[image: current problems]

Third (optional) problem:
I'd like to automatically capitalize (the first word of) the string `seename`. I tried with `\capitalisewords` from package `mfirstuc`, but it doesn't expand and puts the whole word in caps. Any idea?

To solve the first, maybe I could add dots after the description using `\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{\dotfill}`, but I would have to distinguish cases without XRefs, needing that re-definition, from with XRefs cases, which must not have dots between description and cross-references.

The second is due to xindy style, so I need to change that. In the number list section I found this command in an example:

```
\GlsAddXdyLocation{romansc}{:sep "\string\textsc\glsopenbrace"  
 "roman-numbers-lowercase" :sep "\glsclosebrace"}
```

which got me thinking of redefining `\glsclosebrace` with: `\renewcommand*{\glsclosebrace}{}` but it prompts errors of the kind "File ended while scanning for use of \glsgroupheading".

Comment: So I solved the first problem. I looked at the generated files and noticed the page numbers were printed by the `\glsXpageXglsnumberformat` command, command that is defined at the beginning of those file. So I used `\glossaryheader` as an entry point: `\renewcommand*\glossaryheader{\renewcommand*\glsXpageXglsnumberformat[2]{\dotfill\setentrycounter[##1]{page}\glsnumberformat{##2}}}`

Comment: after writing the previous comment I got thinking that using `\glossaryheader` is not such a good idea as it might interfere with some styles. Instead I used `\glossarypreamble`: `\renewcommand*\glossarypreamble{\renewcommand*\glsXpageXglsnumberformat[2]{\dotfill\setentrycounter[##1]{page}\glsnumberformat{##2}}}` even though I can't fathom why I need a *re*newcommand there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st problem,** dots between cross-ref or description and page number:
First, inverting XRef and page number display:

```
\GlsSetXdyLocationClassOrder{%
    "see"
    "arabic-page-numbers"  
    "arabic-section-numbers"  
    "roman-page-numbers"  
    "Roman-page-numbers"  
    "alpha-page-numbers"  
    "Alpha-page-numbers"  
    "Appendix-page-numbers"  
}
```

A bunch of lengths to parametrize the display:

```
\newlength{\stdlinewidth} \setlength{\stdlinewidth}{\linewidth} % width for the content, including page numbers
\newlength{\glsdottedpagerefwidth} % width allocated for the page numbers
\newlength{\glsdottedpagerefwidthoffset} % optional offset between descriptions and page numbers
```

`\glsdottedpagerefwidth`: this is the width allowed for the boxes of the page numbers. It should be set to the widest number there is plus a small space (check out the formatting of the ToC). Eg, if the document is 100+ pages, but less than 1000, it should at least be the width of 000.
`\glsdottedpagerefwidthoffset`: Useless for acronyms. Because descriptions can be long, I find a bloc of text aligned with the end of the dots and the beginning of the page number "column" not very pretty. This is the distance between the end of line for the descriptions and the page number "column".
However, after much fiddling in plain tex, I haven't found a way to have the dots printed as one bloc that does not require to totally hack glossaries (eg, saving description in a box and printing it in page number command :/), hence the dots are obtained with different skips. Not good then.

Actually parametrizing:

```
\setlength{\glsdottedpagerefwidth}{\widthof{0000}}
\setlength{\glsdottedpagerefwidthoffset}{2em}
```

Then, adding the dots:

```
% puttings dots up to the end of line, before page number
\renewcommand*\glossarypreamble{
    \addtolength{\linewidth}{-\glsdottedpagerefwidth-\glsdottedpagerefwidthoffset}
    \renewcommand*\glsXpageXglsnumberformat[2]{%
        \unskip\xleaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill%
        \makebox[0pt][l]{%
            \makebox[\glsdottedpagerefwidth+\glsdottedpagerefwidthoffset][l]{%
            \unskip\xleaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill%
                \makebox[\glsdottedpagerefwidth][r]{%
                    \setentrycounter[##1]{page}\glsnumberformat{##2}%
                }%
            }%
        }%
    }
}
% restoring linewidth: useless, but for a clear conscience.
\renewcommand*\glossarypostamble{\setlength{\linewidth}{\stdlinewidth}}
```

**2nd problem,** commas before the dots:
For entries without cross-refs, no problem: simply redefine `\glspostdescription`.
For entries with cross-refs, I found a dirty(ier) hack in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40590): redefining the command preceding the comma to gobble up one more argument and dismiss it. I also need to restore a dot after the description and before the reference, which I add after taking out any skip LaTeX might have added:

```
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\renewcommand*{\glsseeformat}[4][\seename]{% % 4th "arg" (undelimited one) is the comma
    \unskip. \emph{#1} \glsseelist{#2}}
```

*3rd problem,* capitalise `seename` macro:
A simple redefinition as a total expansion macro does the trick. However, it seems the language is attributed by `printglossary`, so it has to be done in preambule:

```
\renewcommand*\glossarypreamble{
    \let\oldseename\seename
    \edef\seename{\capitalisewords{\oldseename}}
            [ToC style stuff]
}
```

As there can be several glossaries, thus several call to glossarypreamble, we restore the original definition in postamble:

```
\renewcommand*\glossarypostamble{%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{\stdlinewidth}%
    \let\seename\oldseename%
}
```

**conclusion**
All of that is pretty hacky, so if anyone has some alternative solutions I'm very much up for it!
Results:

- voluntary setting the offset to 2em, eg far from a multiple of the 2.9 mm width of the dot boxes, we can notice the difference in skips:[image: Imgur]
- more reasonably set to 6mm, eg more or less twice the width of the dot boxes:[image: Imgur]
- example with acronyms, offset to 0 as there is no description:[image: Imgur]

(the shift between notations and acronym examples is because they are on odd and even pages, respectively)